# CSS3 box-shadow on 1 side

Tags: gradient, css

Is it possible to achieve the following shadow effect in CSS?

[image: Image Shadow]

It needs to go below an image/div.

The closest I have got so far is using

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px -10px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px -10px #999;
box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px -10px #999;
```

Comment: check http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: I have, I'm currently using the same code to achieve the shadow only on one edge. The problem I have is that the shadow in the image has no spread or blur at the bottom - only the side.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the method of putting your image in an image file and displaying the image as an offset background.

Comment: the code you have by the way isn't working in a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be a shadow per se, but I just generated this as a `background` via [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 48%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(48%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 48%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 48%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 48%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 48%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: This used in conjunction with filter blur was pretty much spot on! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Box shadows are possible on one element, all you have to do is separate each box shadow with a comma. For example:

```
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey, -5px 5px 5px blue, 5px -5px 5px orange;
```

This box shadow will produce 3 shadows, one in the top right with a color of grey, one in the bottom left with a color of blue, and one in the bottom right with a color of orange.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/8sfcX/3/) with the demo.

You can play around with the settings but to achieve those curves are quite hard and it might be easier with an image.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code `box-shadow: 0 45px 50px -50px #000000;`